# Type casting an object with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

class `B` extends class `A`. My `factory` function returns an `object` with type `A`.

The `doSomethingWithB` function expects and object with type `B`. If I create a new object with the factory and I'm sure it's type is `B`, how can I narrow the variable type in JSDoc to tell the IDE that the type is not incompatible? Like casting in Java...

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

/**
 * @param {string} type
 * @returns {A}
 */
function factory(type) {

    return new factory.types[type]();
}

/**
 * @type {{A: A, B: B}}
 */
factory.types = {
    'A': A,
    'B': B
}

/**
 * @param {B} bObj
 */
function doSomethingWithB(bObj) {
    console.log(bObj);
}

const bObj = factory('B');

doSomethingWithB(bObj);
```

Comment: What IDE are you using, in IntelliJ ultimate the type shows up fine in the JSDoc, since you clearly state the consuming type. If you want to introspect dynamically created objects, you need to check their type yourself.

Comment: IntelliJ shows a warning at doSomethingWithB(bObj); -> Argument type A is not assignable to parameter type B

Comment: Then change the return, in `factory` to `@returns {A|B}`. You are currently saying this will return only `A`, and you are passing this into `doSomethingWithB` which expects `B`.